# What means immutable, dev... in webpack stats?

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

What means immutable, dev... in webpack stats?

When building a project using webpack I get some stats like:

```
                  Asset      Size  Chunks                         Chunk Names
             index.html  2.31 KiB          [emitted]              
    js/main.920a0304.js  4.93 MiB       0  [emitted] [immutable]  main
js/main.920a0304.js.map  5.42 MiB       0  [emitted] [dev]        main
```

I'm curious about what `[immutable]`, `[dev]` exactly stands for. But, unfortunately, I can't find where these concepts are described. I've googled and searched in webpack docs without success.

Is there any documentation about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/#asset-objects):

**Immutable**:

> A flag telling whether the asset can be long term cached (contains a hash)

(good candidate for a [HTTP immutable asset](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8246))

**Dev**:

> A flag telling whether the asset is only used for development and doesn't count towards user-facing assets